# Android End indeterminate ProgressBar softly

Tags: java, android, progress-bar, android-progressbar

I have a indeterminate Progress Bar that I want to terminate softly.
Setting its visibility status to INVISIBLE or GONE makes it vanish suddenly. I want it to disappear smoothly like I have seen in many other apps I have used...

```
<ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:id="@+id/progress"
    android:indeterminateTint="@color/red"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do an alpha animation when it's time to hide it. You can use `ViewPropertyAnimator`:

To hide smoothly:

```
myView.animate().alpha(0);
```

To show again smoothly:

```
myView.animate().alpha(1);
```

Comment: THANKS man, It worked like a charm... How you guys come up with these solutions?! There is no way I would reach this level of knowledge in the area... and to make it back visible I used same function with parameter replaces with 1.

Comment: yup, that is how you do it. A lot of these things are explained on the android docs. Plus if you watch the android developers blog, you will get up to date with new tricks the platform has for us.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job.

```java
public static final void hideView(final View view, final long durationInMillis)
{
    final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper(), new Handler.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean handleMessage(Message msg)
        {
            if(msg.what > 0) {
                view.setAlpha(1.0F - (msg.what / 10F));
                return true;
            }
            view.setVisibility(View.GONE /* or View.INVISIBLE */);
            return false;
        }
    });

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            long time = (long)(durationInMillis / 10F);
            try {
                for(int i=1; i<=10; i++) {
                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(i);
                    Thread.sleep(time);
                }
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            } finally {
                view.setAlpha(0);
                //Optional
                handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: Many many thanks, It worked but the very simple solution suggested by Cristian Holdunu 
myView.animate().alpha(0); had exactly the same result... So I'm going to go with it. But again I really appreciate the time you spent.